# java array of a class with default value

Tags: java, arrays, default-value

I have a Rational number class with a construtor with a default value of 0/1 called like this:

```
public Rational (){ this(0, 1);}

public Rational (int numerator, int denominator){
    this.numerator = numerator;

    if (denominator== 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator can't be zero.");

    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

Now, in a subclass, I want to create an array of Rationals. They come all set to "null". So I have two methods inside the Rational class that set all values to zero. I have one for a simple array and another for a matrix:

```
public Rational[] zero(Rational[] array){
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        array[i] = new Rational();

    return array;
}

public Rational[][] zero (Rational[][] matrix){
    for (int i=0; i<matrix.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = new Rational();

    return matrix;
}
```

First, would it be better to used improved loops? Something like:

```
public Racional[][] zero(Racional[][] matrix){
    for (Racional[] arr : matrix)
        for (Racional rat : arr)
            rat = new Rational();

    return matrix;
}
```

Second, is there a way to create an array or matrix without having to manually zero all the positions as we can do with primitive types.

e.g.:

```
int[] arr = new int [10];            //All zero
Rational[] arr = new Rational [10];  //All null
arr = arr.zero (arr);                //All "default" - 0/1
```

Comment: Sorry, but Java doesn't do that as far as I am aware.

Comment: For primitive types, you can use `Arrays.fill`.

Comment: @callyalater `Arrays.fill()` works for objects also, but it is applicable here only if `Rational` is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work heavily with arrays and matrices of `Rational`, consider writing static helper methods in `Rational` class:

```
static public Rational[] newArray(int size) {
    Rational[] arr = new Rational[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        arr[i] = new Rational();
    return arr;
}

static public Rational[][] newMatrix(int h, int w) {
    Rational[][] m = new Rational[h][];
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) 
        m[i] = newArray(w);
    return m;
}
```

Then, to instantiate an array or matrix filled with default instances, just call:

```
Rational[] array = Rational.newArray(10);
```

or

```
Rational[][] matrix = Rational.newMatrix(10, 5);
```

Comment: Yep. Works just fine. And it is simple to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using an immutable `Rational` class,

```
public static class Rational {
    public final int num, denom;
    public Rational() {num = denom =0;}
    public Rational(int num, int denom) {this.num=num; this.denom=denom;}
}
```

It can be done like this:

```
public static void zero(Rational[][] mat) {
    Rational def = new Rational();
    for (Rational[] arr : mat) {
        Arrays.fill(arr, def);
    }
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    Rational[][] mat = new Rational[5][5];
    zero(mat);
}
```

"Automatic" default initialization something like C++ is not possible here. Also, your nested "new-style" `for` loops don't work because setting `rat = new Rational()` only reassigns the temporary, `rat`, not the value in the array.

As you can see, this fills the matrix with the **same** default `Rational`. This is an obvious performance and memory-use optimization with immutable `Rational`, and avoids repeated constructor calls. If you have mutable `Rational` (which I would discourage), this is almost certainly catastrophically wrong: changing one value will change them all. In this case, you will probably do best with the nested "old-style" `for` loops. (I think an outer "new-style" `for` loop with an inner "old-style" `for` loop would not be as easy to read, but is certainly feasible.)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I think you commented before I edited my answer to include that information :-)

Comment: I have a mutable Rational. I do change the values of the rationals (in some cases, an entire row). So for would it be better to "create a new Matrix" everytime I change a row? Or should I keep my mutable style?

Comment: @J.F. I would think that `Rational` should be immutable, and setting it can be done like this: `mat[5][2] = mat[5][2].multiply(otherRational);`, etc.?

Comment: As Rational is mutable, I have something like this when I try to multiply:        `this.numerator = this.numerator * otherRational.numerator;` (same for denominator). And void as return. So, If I go for immutable, I should change like this `int num = this.numerator * otherRational.numerator;`    and then I return a Rational as `return new Rational (num, den);`. Right? Wise to do it like this?

Comment: @J.F. That's how to do it. It is often wise to do it this way, but it's up to you. For instance, `java.lang.String`does everything this way, but you have to decide if this suits your needs. Read comments on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151733, and maybe http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/01/13/immutable-types-understand-them-and-use-them/ for more.

Comment: @J.F. though not explicitly documented, it is common for Java to have immutable "value classes": `String`, all wrapper classes (`Integer`, `Byte`, `Long` etc), `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `Instant` and many others.

Comment: @J.F. the only exception to this rule is `java.util.Date`, but mutablility of `Date` is considered a design flaw, and all mutation methods there are deprecated.

Comment: @J.F. to learn a best practice, take a look at `BigDecimal` for example. 1) It has several `.valueOf()` factory methods (to avoid `new` in instantiation; nowadays it is common to shorten to `.of()`--as it is done in `LocalDate` for example). 2) It has several constants for common values, like `BigDecimal.TEN` or `BigDecimal.ZERO`. 3) To perform operations are used instance methods that return result of operation, like `bd = bd.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(2))`

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Indeed. Three `.valueOf()` methods in `BigDecimal`. And all methods have a "non-void" return.